# Xpath and selecting different info in the same table row

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have an xpath query that returns the description of a td (with a width of 60) from a table row. I pull between 0 and 30 rows per query.

```
$textTags = $xpath->query( '//table/tr/td[@width=60]' );
```

each table row looks like this

```
<tr>
<td width=60 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>Description</b></td>
<td align=center width=80><img src='http://></td>
<td width=50 bgcolor='#ffffcc' align=center><b>1</b></td>
<td bgcolor='#ffffcc'><b>Toy</b></td>
<input type='hidden'  name='obj_id_3' value='20885'><input type='hidden' name='oldcost_3'  value='0'></td>
<td align=center bgcolor='#ffffcc'><input type='text' name='cost_3' size=6 maxlength=5 value='0'></td>
<td width=180 bgcolor='#ffffcc'><i>more text</i></td>
<td width=40 bgcolor='#ffffcc' align=center><select name=back_to_inv[20885]>
<tr>this continues on a max of 30 times</tr>
```

I run through a loop to get this info:

```
foreach ( $textTags as $tag ){
$item = $tag->nodeValue;
}
```

I get the description text I need. However, there is the 'hidden' input type with a `name=obj_id_3` and a `value=20885` that I need to get with each corresponding pass. How do I get those hidden input values in addition, that are part of the current tr I'm looking at? Each tr has only 1 record that I need to access so I don't have to worry about multiple, the table you see above is how every table looks, minus the unique description and hidden name and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an or to query the input separately.  Something like

```
$xpath->query("//table/tr/td[@width=60]|//table/tr/input[contains(@id, 'obj_id')]");
```

Comment: you put obj_id here and it changes. do i need like an obj)id* or something?

Comment: how do i access this second query in my for/each loop?

Comment: It's not a separate query .. it will iterate over all the elements it finds (so in this case it should alternate) or you can check the node type

Comment: Thanks This does work for me. When this loops in my foreach, it only recognizes the left side of the union, and then on the second pass, it recognizes the obj_id side of the union, effectively breaking it up. Is there any way around this? capture both sides of the union on only one foreach loop?

Comment: @KiloJKilo it wouldn't make sense to get multiple elements simultaneously like that .. they would have to be grouped themselves.  You'd need a different xml structure, pass through XSLT to create that or something.  I think it would be a waste of your time, though.  Don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer helps!

Comment: they are grouped, in the tr. the text element I want and the hidden input are all contained in different td's of the same row. `<tr><td width 60>first side of union<td><td><td><td><input type hidden second side of union><tr><tr>...`

Comment: Then you can do something like query on the TRs and in that loop run two separate queries that look for these children (either with XPath or just normal node inspeciton)

Comment: thanks. I am going to experiment with this. For now, I just create a multidimensional array.